# Why am I not able to filter out the duplicates on JS?

Tags: javascript

The server generates a random character (a-z) or digit (0-9), and takes in one target input from user. I tried to ensure the target is not duplicated by splitting the var characters then joining them. However the server will randomly generate and some are duplicates. I tried using the filter() method but I still have duplicates. Whats the problem here? :/

```
<html> 
<tr>
        <td width="20%">The target option:</th>
        <td width="20%"> 
        <input type="text" name="option" id="target" placeholder="Input option">
        <span id="wrongTarget"></span>
        </td> 
</tr>
<script>
function generateOptions() 
{
    var maxOptions = 9; //generate 9 different options + 1 target 
    target = document.getElementById("target").value; //get the target (any digits/char) 
    var reg = /^.$/; //this is to take in an input 
    var characters = 'zxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiop0123456789'; 
    var random = ""; 
    optionArr = []; 
    
    if (reg.test(target) == false) //check for valid input 
    {
        document.getElementById("wrongTarget").innerHTML = "Only one character is allowed";
        optionArr.push(target); 
        return false; 
    }
        optionArr.push(target); 

    for (var x = 0; x < maxOptions; x++)
    {
        characters = characters.split(target).join(""); //to ensure target is not duplicated
        random = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)); // produce random number 
        optionArr.push(random);
    }
    
    //remove the duplicates 
    optionArr.filter((item, index) => {
    return optionArr.indexOf(item) === index 
    });
    console.log(optionArr);
}
</script></html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Filter returns new array, so you should do `optionArr = optionArr.filter(....)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateOptions() {
  var maxOptions = 9; //generate 9 different options + 1 target
  target = document.getElementById("target").value; //get the target (any digits/char)
  var reg = /^.$/; //this is to take in an input
  var characters = "zxcvbnmasdfghjklqwertyuiop0123456789";
  var random = "";
  optionArr = [];

  if (reg.test(target) == false) {
    //check for valid input
    document.getElementById("wrongTarget").innerHTML =
      "Only one character is allowed";
    optionArr.push(target);
    return false;
  }
  optionArr.push(target);

  for (var x = 0; x < maxOptions; x++) {
    characters = characters.split(target).join(""); //to ensure target is not duplicated
    random = characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)); // produce random number
    optionArr.push(random);
  }

  //remove the duplicates
  var filteredArry = optionArr.filter((item, index) => {
    return optionArr.indexOf(item) === index;
  });
  console.log(filteredArry);
}

generateOptions();
```

```html
<html>
<tr>
  <td width="20%">The target option:</th>
  <td width="20%">
    <input type="text" name="option" id="target" placeholder="Input option">
    <span id="wrongTarget"></span>
  </td>
</tr>

</html>
```